# Re-running Calculate Field tool in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

Calculated a field with a little ArcPy function yesterday and now I want to change it. Just realized that the function I defined, once run and the geoprocessing pane is closed, disappears.

Is there a way to add the function to the gdb toolbox so I can edit and re-run at will?

Comment: What's a gdb toolbox?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, no it won't save the process in the geoprocessing results window if you run the script in the python window in an ArcGIS session or in an external IDE. However, if you create a Python toolbox from your script the results will be saved in the geoprocessing results window each time you run it in your session.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-python-toolboxes.htm

Comment: Thank you Pdavis. A few minutes after posting the question I remembered to go to the History tab in the Catalog. Right-clicking on the action gives me everything I asked for: opening it to edit, re-running, and saving as script. I will go ahead and create a python toolbox and save this into it. Thanks!